# como estructurar una consulta usando unión con clave compuesta

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy tratando de hacer una unión entre tablas mediante linq donde la clave que las une debe ser compuesta por dos campos

```
var devengados = (from inten in ctx.INTENCIONES
                  join contr in ctx.CONTRATOS on inten.intencion_id equals contr.intencion_id
                  join intFin in ctx.INTENCIONES_FINANCIAMIENTO on new { inten.intencion_id, inten.orden } equals new { intFin.intencion_id, intFin.orden }
                  where contr.contrato_id == iContratoId
                  select new { inten, contr, intFin }).First();
```

Con esta estructura tengo error en el join de intFin:

> Error  31  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate que los tipos y nombres de las propiedades que estas comparando coincidan. Intenta lo siguiente:

```
new { p1 = inten.intencion_id, p2 = inten.orden } equals new { p1 = intFin.intencion_id, p2 = intFin.orden }
```

Si tienes diferentes tipos de datos, intenta hacer las conversiones necesarias, como lo siguiente:

```
new { p1 = inten.intencion_id, p2 = (int)inten.orden } equals new { p1 = intFin.intencion_id, p2 = intFin.orden }
```

También asegúrate que no estés comparando una propiedad `nulleable` con otra con no lo es, si este es el caso también puedes hacer una conversión como la siguiente:

```
new { p1 = inten.intencion_id, p2 = (int?)inten.orden } equals new { p1 = intFin.intencion_id, p2 = intFin.orden }
```

Comment: si coinciden los tipos, de cada lado intencion_id es int y orden es short

Comment: Y  ya intentaste poniéndole nombre (p1, p2) a las propiedades que estas comparando? Te da el mismo error?

Comment: Gracias, aplique las segerencias pero a todos, ya habia aplicado los nombres pero crep que la diferencia fueron los nulleable: `join intFin in ctx.INTENCIONES_FINANCIAMIENTO on new { p1 = (int?)inten.intencion_id, p2 = (int?)inten.orden } equals new { p1 = (int?)intFin.intencion_id, p2 = (int?)intFin.orden }`

Comment: Que bien! me alegra que te halla funcionado.